# Trigger a series of SMS alerts over time using Twilio/ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sms, twilio

I didn't see a situation quite like mine, so here goes:

Scenario highlights: The user wants a system that includes custom SMS alerts. A component of the functionality is to have a way to identify a start based on user input, then send SMS with personalized message according to a pre-defined interval after the trigger.  I've never used Twilio before and am noodling around with the implementation.

First Pass Solution: Using Twilio account, I designated the .aspx that will receive the inbound triggering alert/SMS via GET. The receiving page declares and instantiates my SMSAlerter object within page load, which responds immediately with a first SMS and kicks off the System.Timer.Timer. Elementary, and functional to a point.

Problem: The alerts continue to be sent if the interval for the timer is a short time span. I tested it at a minute interval and was successful. When I went to 10 minutes, the immediate SMS is sent and the first message 10 minutes later is sent, but nothing after that.

My Observation: Since there is no interaction with the resource after the inbound text, the Session times out if left at default 20 minutes. Increasing Session timeout doesn't work, and even if it did does not seem correct since the interval will be on the order of hours, not minutes.

Using Cache to store each new SMSAlerter might be the way to go. For any SMSAlerter that is created, the schedule is used for roughly 12 hours and is replaced with a new SMSAlerter object when the same user notifies the system the following day. Is there a better way? Am I over/under-simplifying? I am not anticipating heavy traffic now (tens of users), but the user is thinking big.

Thank you for comments, suggestions. I didn't include the code, because the question is about design, not syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I think your timer is going out of scope about 20 minutes after the original request, killing the timer. I have a feeling that if you keep refreshing the aspx page it won't happen - but obviously that doesn't help much.

You could launch a new thread that has the System.Timers.Timer object so it stays alive, and doesn't go out of scope when there are no follow up requests to the server. But this isn't a great idea to be honest - although it might help with understanding the issue.

Ultimately, you'll need some sort of continuously running service - as you don't want to depend on the app pool for this, so I'd suggest a Windows Service running in the background to handle it, which is going to be suitable for a long term solution.

Hope this helps!

(Edited slightly to make the windows service aspect clearer)

Comment: Thanks! I was so focused on the session issue that I hadn't gotten as far as what would happen if the app has an interruption of service/recycles. Will investigate and update.